# Is it possible to unit test a WindowController thats initialised with a nib?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, nib, xctest

I have a simple Mac OS application that comes with the default `MainMenu.xib`. In there I have a second window for preferences and a `PreferencesWindowController`. I'd like to get the following test working:

```
@implementation TestPreferencesWindow

- (void)testProtectsUserPasswordByUsingAPasswordField
{
    PreferencesWindowController *controller = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainMenu"];
    XCTAssertInstanceOf([[controller passwordField] class], NSSecureTextField);
}

@end
```

The problem is that `[controller passwordField]` is not initialised (because the nib isn't loading?) so it always returns `nil`.

How do I tell the nib to create all the bindings?

When I call `[controller window]` is gives the error, and returns `nil`:

```
Could not connect the action orderFrontStandardAboutPanel: to target of class PreferencesWindowController
```

For debugging I have tried the following:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
XCTAssertNotNil(bundle);
NSString *nibPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MainMenu" ofType:@"nib"];
XCTAssertNotNil(nibPath); 

PreferencesWindowController *controller = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibPath:nibPath owner:self];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", [controller window], [controller passwordField]);
```

However it still prints `(null) (null)` ...

To get rid of the warning:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
XCTAssertNotNil(bundle);
NSString *nibPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MainMenu" ofType:@"nib"];
XCTAssertNotNil(nibPath);

NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
PreferencesWindowController *controller = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibPath:nibPath owner:app];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", [controller window], [controller passwordField]);
```

No more warning, but still prints `(null) (null)` .. I feel like I'm getting closer though...

Comment: Is MainMenu.xib added to your unit test target?

Comment: I didn't think of that bug it didn't make a difference. If I purposely put a nib name that doesn't exist it doesn't report any error either...

Comment: Well, the method is expected to return nil if it can't find the nib.

Comment: Both the main target and test target show the MainMenu.xib in red in the Copy Bundle Resources phase (as if the file does not exist) ... is that right? I should also point out that the application obviously loads the windows correctly.

Comment: Hey Elliot, Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. Write below method in your .m file, and declare public in .h file

**MyWindowController.m file**

```
- (instancetype)initWithWindowNibPath:(NSString *)nibPath {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibPath:nibPath owner:self];
    if(self)
    {
        //initialize stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

**MyWindowController.h file**

```
- (instancetype)initWithWindowNibPath:(NSString *)nibPath;
```

Now write your code:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
XCTAssertNotNil(bundle);
NSString *nibPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MyWindowController" ofType:@"nib"];
XCTAssertNotNil(nibPath); 

MyWindowController *controller = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibPath:nibPath];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", [controller window], [controller passwordField]);
```

This is works perfect for me.

**Reason:**
owner value not properly set in initWithWindowNibPath method and therefore not set class's properties NSOutlet to nib's control.