# is it Possible to perform XCT Test for non return types in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xctest

Can any one help me ..Is there any provision or way to perform XCT test case for a non return type in iOS.I have performed XCT Test cases for the return types.But explored a lot on performing XCT Test cases on the non return types but i was not able to find a way.

Comment: What do you mean non return type??

Comment: If the function doesn't return anything the you need to check the outside variable which are affected by the function.

Comment: non return type ..Like Void Methods

Comment: Which things do the void methods do???

Comment: it doesn't return any thing ..non return type ..

Comment: I already answered.
Refer this stack-overflow answer link:
[Is it possible to unit test a WindowController thats initialised with a nib?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086277/is-it-possible-to-unit-test-a-windowcontroller-thats-initialised-with-a-nib/32689186#32689186